# Vue 2.0, where to place local functions

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Where do you correctly place local functions in vue 2.x?

I could just place them in the "methods" object, but I'd like them to be completely local to the instance if thats possible.

Sort of like this in Plain JS :

```
window._global = (function () {
  function _secretInsideFunct(){
    return "FooBar";
  }

  var __localObject = {
    outsideFunct : function () {
      return _secretInsideFunct();
    }
  }
return __localObject;
}());
```

..where `_global._secretInsideFunct()` wouldnt be accessible anywhere else but from inside the _global object.

In this specific case I want to make a function that creates an array object if it doesn't exist..  Something like:

```
function CreateOrSet (workArray, itemName, itemValue ){
                        var salaryRow = self.Status.Rows.find(r => r.recordID == itemName);
                        if (!salaryRow) {
                            salaryRow = { recordID: itemName, recordAmount: 0, recordName: "Løn" };
                            self.Status.Rows.push(salaryRow);
                        }
                        salaryRow.recordAmount = itemValue ;
}
```

..but a general approach for these cases is better :)

Comment: What is the function for? You can create an object just like your `global`, and register it as a vue plugin, or use it directly.

Comment: In this case its for creating an array item if it doesn't exist allready.

I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this function doesn't looks like a utility or helper function, but relate to a state, `Status.Rows`. If I were you, I will define it as close as to the state or the module that the state being used.

If the state will be used across the app, maybe I will define it in entry file, `index.js` or `app.vue`.

Or If you are using `vuex`, you can define it as an `vuex` `action`. So you may do something like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: {
      rows: []
  },
  mutations: {
    pushRow (state, salaryRow) {
      state.status.rows.push(salaryRow)
    },
    changeAmount (state, id, amount) {
      const salaryRow = state.status.Rows.find(r => r.recordID === id)
      salaryRow.recordAmount = amount
    }
  },
  actions: {
    createRow (context, itemName) {
      const salaryRow = { recordID: itemName, recordAmount: 0, recordName: "Løn" };
      context.commit('pushRow', salaryRow)
    }
  }
})
```

You can put all of the code to a single action, it is just an idea, how you organize your code depend on your needs.